# How to get band information from network?

Tags: android, network-programming

I want to display the network frequency(Band) which device is using to connect with internet.
I found an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.v_a_v.netmonitor) that does this without root.
I have no idea how to do this. I am able to get Rat information using following code:

```
public String getNetworkClass(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info == null || !info.isConnected())
            return "-"; //not connected
        if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return "WIFI";
        if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            int networkType = info.getSubtype();
            Log.d("locknet", "networkType: " + networkType);
            switch (networkType) {
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: //api<8 : replace by 11
                    return "2G";
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: //api<9 : replace by 14
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:  //api<11 : replace by 12
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:  //api<13 : replace by 15
                    return "3G";
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:    //api<11 : replace by 13
                    return "4G";
                default:
                    return "UNKNOWN";
            }
        }
        return "?";
    }
```

I searched over the internet but found nothing.

Please help me to get band information. I shall be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get ARFCN and then map to get the band.

Use below code and then do the rest by yourself. 
Check [this](http://niviuk.free.fr/lte_band.php)

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
CellInfo ci = tm.getAllCellInfo().get(0) ; // Registered Cell Tower

if (ci instanceof CellInfoGsm)  {
  ((CellInfoGsm)ci).getCellIdentity().getArfcn();
} else if (ci instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
  ((CellInfoWcdma)ci).getCellIdentity().getUarfcn();
} else if (ci instanceof CellInfoLte) {
  ((CellInfoLte)ci).getCellIdentity().getEarfcn();
}
```

Comment: @Vatish Sharma Can you please also upvote the answer? This may help other people